# How to copy input data from one component to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, state

I am new to React and practicing data transfers with form. I have a basic form like this.

[image: Component]

I want users to select an appliance from the dropdown menu and enter the zip code. When they click on go, they are redirected to another page that has other details to be filled out. like this:

[image: Another Component (Linked through react-router]

Now the second page can be accessed from other links where they may not have filled the two inputs before, so what I want is for users is to get the two inputs preloaded on the second form so as to avoid wasting time. Something like this:

[image: Component]

The code for the first component

```
                   <div >
                        <FormControl style={{width: '60%'}}>
                            <NativeSelect
                            id="demo-customized-select-native"
                            input={<BootstrapInput />}
                            >
                            <option aria-label="Appliance" value="" />
                            <option value={10}>Washing Machine</option>
                            <option value={20}>Clothes Dryer</option>
                            <option value={30}>Dishwasher</option>
                            <option value={40}>Refrigerator</option>
                            <option value={50}>Freezer</option>
                            <option value={60}>Range</option>
                            <option value={70}>Cooktop </option>
                            <option value={80}>Oven </option>
                            <option value={90}>Microwave</option>
                            <option value={100}>Trash Compactor</option>
                            </NativeSelect>
                        </FormControl>&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Typography variant="h6">
                         in&nbsp;
                        </Typography>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <FormControl style={{width: '60%'}}>
                            <BootstrapInput type="text" id="demo-customized-textbox" placeholder="Zip Code"/>
                        </FormControl>  &nbsp;   
                    </div>
                    <div style={{paddingTop: '1em'}}>
                                        Go
                            </Button>
                    </div>
```

and the code for the second component

```
<div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Box elevation={12} container>
          <Grid className={classes.gridSpace} container spacing={1}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={7}>
              <h1 className={classes.h1}>Request a repair online</h1>
              <p className={classes.bodyText}>Fill in the form and get a <b>free</b> call back with <b>free</b> quotation!</p>
              <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="Name"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="phone"
                label="Phone"
                type="tel"
                id="phone"
                autoComplete="phone"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="zipcode"
                label="Zip Code"
                name="zipcode"
                autoComplete="zipcode"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth >
                <InputLabel  id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label" >Appliances</InputLabel>
                <Select
                id="َAppliances"
                label="َAppliances"              
                >
                <MenuItem value="">
                    <em></em>
                </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Washing Machine</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Clothes Dryer</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Dishwasher</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={40}>Refrigerator</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={50}>Freezer</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={60}>Range</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={70}>Cooktop </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={80}>Oven </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={90}>Microwave</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={100}>Trash Compactor</MenuItem>
            </Select>
           </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="Date"
                type="date"
                name="date"
                autoComplete="date"
              />
              <FormHelperText>Preferred Date for Service</FormHelperText>
            </Grid> 
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="Time"
                type="time"
                min="08:00" 
                max="16:00"
                name="Time"
                autoComplete="Time"
              />
              <FormHelperText>Preferred Time for Service - Office Hours: 8:00 AM to 4:00 PM</FormHelperText>
            </Grid>
            
            </Grid>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: '2em'}}>
                <Button
                    style={{backgroundColor: '#173f5f', color: 'white',  height: '3em'}}
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                >
                    {<Typography style={{fontFamily: 'ubuntu', textTransform: 'none'}}>Request a Call Back</Typography>}
                </Button>
            </div>
```

How Do I implement this if I want to use react hooks and not class components? Please help.

Comment: Check my answer below and this link : https://reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath/params-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your routes (react-router-dom) to pass props (params in react-router-dom) from one page to another.

Example :

To pass the zipcode and device value from Home page to Request page, in your App.js file, your route should look like this:

```
<Route path="/request/:zipcode/:device" render={props => <Request {...props} />} />
```

and, in your Home page, the "Go" button must have this path:

```
<Link to={`/request/${zipcode}/${device}`}>
  <button type="button">Go</button>
</Link>
```

Check my demo : [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wrdfzy?file=src%2FHome.js) to understand

---

**EDIT 1**

New demo with Validation (react-boostrap) before changing page and submitting the form.

Link: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-elujrx?file=src%2FHome.js)

---

**EDIT 2**

Demo with Material-ui + react-hook-form for validation

Link: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c7jnpy?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I implemented this method but the first form can be uploaded without filling the details. It has no validation, how can I validate the first form so that it does not proceed with empty fields?

Comment: @WaseemAbdullahi check my edited answer with new demo (validation)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want, but I have worked with Material UI with my other forms, how do I work with bootstrap in the same project? is is possible?

Comment: @WaseemAbdullahi Material or Bootstrap, it doesn't matter ...
You just need to add the validation to the form fields by following the Material documentation. (https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/)
The most important are the HandleSubmit functions and the imports (react-router-dom)

Comment: @WaseemAbdullahi package to complete Material : react-material-ui-form-validator (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator)

Comment: the react-material-ui -form validator uses class component, class components are slower than functional components. I will look into the video you shared, thanks once again. I understand the logic but since I am new to coding, I cannot code it properly. my coding syntax is weak

Comment: @WaseemAbdullahi check my second edit with Material-ui & react-hook-form :)

Comment: You are literally a life saver! Much obliged, thank you so much!